# Android Close Alert Dialog box and Activity together

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

In my android application I have an alertdialog box will open as sson as the activity is created and based on the text given in that alertdialog search is done and result is displayed in a listview. But when I am clicking the backbutton, alert dialog close first and then again I need to click back button to close the current activity. But I need to close both alert dialog and Activity in one back button click.I am giving the code below.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;

    public SampleTest() {
        alertDialog = null;
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_branch_list);



        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.search_branch_predict, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

        final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.edittext);

        final Button btnSearch = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.search_Button);


        // create alert dialog
        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();

}
}
}
```

Comment: show your OnBackPressed Code

Comment: if you are calling `finish()` in `onBackPressed()` it will finish the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
@Override  
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{  
     //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
     if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
     {  

        dialog.dismiss();
        finish();

     }  
     return true;  
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    dialog.dismiss();
    finish();
}
```

Edit 1:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.id.YOUR_LAYOU_ID_HERE, this);

mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int eid = event.getAction();
            switch (eid) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                finish();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This may helps you.

Comment: A layoutinflator and view is there.. I think I need to close that view and then activity

Comment: yeah try to close view and then activity.

Comment: do u know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Override onBackPressed() in your activity and check for is your alert dialog box is open then called finish to kill activity.

```
    @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
    if(alertDialog.isShowing()){
     alertDilaog.dismiss(); // this will dismiss your dialog
     finish(); // this will kill your activity
    }else{
     super.onBackPressed();   
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override onBackPressed() method as:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
        yourActivity.this.finish();
    }
```